# Creating probability of occurrence map in ArcMap Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, regression

I am trying to figure out how to create a map representing probability of some phenomena occurrence. I have a binary raster (1- phenomena exists; 0 - doesn't exist) and several raster that explain this phenomena (temperature, precipitation, slope and etc.).

Could you advise on steps I need to take to have this map?

I tried to use different regression tools in ArcMap Pro, but seems that they don't suit my situation?

Comment: When you say “ArcMap Pro”, do you mean ArcGIS Pro or ArcMap?

Comment: You need to specify a model, most likely a logistic regression type approach. However, ArcPro does have the Random Forests model available, which would be quite suitable for your needs.

Comment: I meant ArcGIS Pro

Comment: @JeffreyEvans yes, I also was thinking about logistic or binary regression. Is it an additional tool in ArcPro?